# Help me redirecting

Tags: code-golf, string

Your task is to automatically complete URLs like the address bar in most  browsers is doing. We will use the following (simplified) rules:

- If the input string starts with `http://`, `ftp://` or `https://`, return the string unchanged.
- Otherwise, if the input string contains a dot `.`, e.g. `in.put` then the HTTP is assumed and `http://` is prepended: `http://in.put`.
- Otherwise `ftp://` is prepended, e.g. `ftp://input` when the input string was `input`.

### Input

Any string which must not necessarily be a valid URL.

### Output

The string modified according to the above rules.

### Test Cases

```
dan-pc -> ftp://dan-pc
https://localhost/ -> https://localhost/
ftp://foo -> ftp://foo
http://foo -> http://foo
f.oo -> http://f.oo
derp.me -> http://derp.me
another.one/ ->http://another.one/
// -> ftp://// 
a://b -> ftp://a://b
```

*This is code golf, shortest code wins. Good Luck!*

Comment: Can the input be `abcd://site`? (generally if there is something before `://` can we assume it's http, https or ftp?

Comment: nope. You do not have to take care of "invalid" input. Yes , your assumption is right @user202729

Comment: Then which inputs are valid?

Comment: If the input might be `abcd://lol` it results in `ftp://abcd://lol`
Having to check invalid input seemed like a overkill to me.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a test case for `http://foo`

Comment: Can the input be an arbitrary string? It looks like answers are assuming it's formatted like a URL.

Comment: the input is string, but if your language has a better solution go for it. It isn't clearly defined, so any in/output is allowed as long as the output matches the testcases. @xnor

Comment: @ChasBrown **edited.**

Comment: @HermanLauenstein *Everything* is valid, the constraints to construct the url should be clear, however here are your examples:
`// -> ftp:////  a://b -> http://a://b`

Comment: I find the explanation very confusing. It talks about a search bar, but doesn't appear to support searching. It talks about writing a browser which supports redirecting, but doesn't seem to actually fetch anything.

Comment: It seems also that the last test case is not following the rules, as `a://b` doesn't contain a `.` and so should be output as `ftp://a://b`

Comment: Additionally, the last test case does not agree with 0x45's earlier reply to @user202729.

Comment: Sorry, I was doing this parallel to actual work. Fixed it.

Comment: Suggested test case: `"p://"`, which should map to `"ftp://p://"`

Comment: What about `ftps://`?

Comment: @Titus, read the previous comments and the description conscientious. *Otherwise, if the input string contains a dot ., e.g. in.put then the HTTP is assumed and http:// is prepended: http://in.put.* There is no dot, so it should be `ftp://<input>`

Answer (score 3):

## R, 98 bytes

```r
x=scan()
cat(`if`(grepl("^(https?|ftp)://",x),"",`if`(grepl("\\.",x),"http://","ftp://")),x,sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT0OTKzmxRCMhMy1BI70otSBHQym6oKY41kpfX0mnQlNHSUkHWU4PIphRUlIAVqGUBmFoaupU6BSnFtgqKWn@/6@UkpinW5CsBAA)

Comment: This won't quite work, for a couple of reasons: the regex `.` in the second `grepl` matches any single character, you need `\\.` instead. Additionally, the first `grepl` will match anything that has `p://` or `s://` as a substring; you need to use a regex like others have used, `^(https?|ftp)://`

Comment: Whoops, you're right about the latter grepl, fixed that.  But the first one correctly matches all the test cases as they currently stand, I can update this if need be.  Or is that considered bad form?

Comment: The input is specified as `Any string which must not necessarily be a valid URL.` so I _think_ you need that update. Which is annoying, to be sure. String challenges in R are seldom fun :(

Comment: Damn, you're right.  That'll learn me to read the instructions better.  Fixed, and thanks for reigning me in =)

Comment: not a problem, I've been burned so many times before...I must have ten or so answers I deleted for not meeting the specs that I never went back to. =P

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 38 bytes

```perl
m%://%||s%.*\.%http://$&%||s%^%ftp://%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z9X1UpfX7WmplhVTytGTzWjpKQAKKCiBhaKU00Dc1X//0/Lz/@XX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNDgv24BAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>63</s> <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```ruby
->a{a[%r*(https?|ftp)://*]?a:"#{a[?.]?'ht':?f}tp://"+a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcyxDsIgEIDhV2lqTLWmsJMocXJ3cGkYTgphqO0FroMpPPtJnL8/f9zeX/ZXHm6ww3iM/SkQYdLZE56VlL3RoNpDNS2M7gJ1SvtCWKm9QOH78/ESDmzYc8oNbpQaPyZTmCdYBrT839V6Xi3MYU0keXIRxcf9AA)

Comment: Erm your code just works if you supply the result in your code...?

Comment: They were hardcoded tests, now it should be more dynamic

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift](http://rextester.com/l/swift_online_compiler), <s>147</s> 133 bytes

Thanks to [Herman L](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70894/herman-l) for saving 14 bytes.

Sadly, `NSRegularExpression` would've taken away lots of precious bytes.

```
import Foundation;let s=readLine()!,h=["http://","https://","ftp://"];print(h.contains{s.hasPrefix($0)} ?s:h[s.contains(".") ?0:2]+s)
```

**Prettyfied:**

```
import Foundation

let s = readLine()!, h = ["http://","https://","ftp://"]
print(h.contains{ s.hasPrefix($0) } ? s :h[s.contains(".") ? 0 : 2] + s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcqxCsIwEIDhV4nBIcGSFnFKKd06ObiXDsEm5EAvIXeiID57BAtuHz8/PSHwqVa451RYTOmBq2NI2N88CxqKd@sZ0Cu9a@Iwy8icbdvK5ifaGLa29LkAsormmpAdIL3JREeX4gO81L7THzGSjTP9ByWN1GLs7HE5kK7VYeLoi0novw)

Comment: I managed to remove a few bytes: [TIO](https://tio.run/##PcqxCsIwEIDhV4nBIcGSFnFKKd06ObiXDsEm5EAvIXeiID57BAtuHz8/PSHwqVa451RYTOmBq2NI2N88CxqKd@sZ0Cu9a@Iwy8icbdvK5ifaGLa29LkAsormmpAdIL3JREeX4gO81L7THzGSjTP9ByWN1GLs7HE5kK7VYeLoi0novw)

Comment: @HermanL Wow, impressive! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>87</s> 85 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.match('(https?|ftp)://',s)and s or['f','ht']['.'in s]+'tp://'+s
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxNCoMwEIXX9RTZjWKq0KVgexDrIpqkETQTMrMp9O5pIpTu3s/3XnizQ39LdnymXR2LVoKGaLpD8epqqB1zoMfHcmiGvgdJjfJakMA4gQUJjmGeoIPNC5pb4FColqrtCBhZRJMsxsznfgKt/DWsIAWctxndcVW7Q@K@pPacW8RitImhO0yRyiM7Ezv0pv@t/6BaVp2dsS@Yh@oS4uZZkITxDtLW1KQv)

-2 bytes thx to [Titus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55735/titus) and [wastl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78123/wastl)

Comment: Maybe `re.match(r'://',s)` should be enough

Comment: @tsh: It´s not. Look at the latest test case. But I´d personally say that `^(ht|f)tps?://` should be ok.

Comment: I don't think ftps is considered a valid protocol. But you can save two bytes by removing r and ^ (re.match does only apply the regex at the beginning)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 64 bytes

```
x=>x.match`^(https?|ftp)://`?x:`${/\./.test(x)?'ht':'f'}tp://`+x
```

## JavaScript, <s>51</s> 50 bytes, Real life assumption

```
x=>x.match`//`?x:`${/\./.test(x)?'ht':'f'}tp://`+x
```

Thank tsh for 1 byte

Comment: `'htt':'ft'}p` -> `'ht':'f'}tp`

Comment: Won't this fail for `abcd://site`? Expected output is `ftp://abcd://site`.

Comment: @Shaggy That's why I say "Real life assumption". In comment such are invalid input

Comment: No, the comments were clarifying that those inputs *were* valid but inputs with an invalid protocol should be treated the same as inputs with no protocol. The test cases have been updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (Firefox 52), 41 bytes

```
s=>new URL(s,/\./.test(s)?'http:':'ftp:')
```

If a string is required for output, add 3 bytes `+''` at the end. (Notice this solution may add a trailing `/` at the end of domain name since they are the same URL)

```js
f=
s=>new URL(s,/\./.test(s)?'http:':'ftp:')

t=s=>console.log(`${s} -> ${f(s)}`)

t('example.com')
t('example')
t('http://example')
t('https://example')
t('ftp://example')
t('http://example.com')
t('https://example.com')
t('ftp://example.com')
```

It seems this only works on Firefox 52 ESR but not Firefox 60 or Chrome 65. So sad.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>74</s> 72 bytes

```java
s->s.matches("(https?|ftp)://.*")?s:(s.contains(".")?"ht":"f")+"tp://"+s
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@HermanLauenstein*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY/BbsMgDIbvfQqLE6wKuafa@gTtZcepB5eQJR0BFLuVqi3PnnlZLjtMqQQSmM/@Py54w@JSf0wuIBEcsIufG4Aush8adB6OP1eAVx66@A5OLwcyO6mPsmURI3cOjhDhGSYqXsj2yK71pJVumTPtvxrOpipL@6TMnipN1qXIkiaIlZJqWVWqUWarOAuntjTtfqfn6znI9CXklroaemlcTN5OaBbFO7HvbbqyzfLCIeponVY1xiI7ZWbj/7HZU5JDchjaRFyutjSzapPSKln7Idver3IYE7d@sCk@wNbuPPuGh/72x3TcjNM3)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->                   // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  s.matches("(https?|ftp)://.*")?
                      //  If the input starts with one of
                      //  "http://", "https://", or "ftp://"
   s                  //   Return it as is
  :                   //  Else:
   (s.contains(".")?  //   If it contains a dot
     "ht"             //    Start with "ht"
    :                 //   Else:
     "f")             //    Start with "f"
   +"tp://"+s         //   And append "tp://" and the input-String
```

Comment: -2 bytes using `s->s.matches("(https?|ftp)://.*")?s:(s.contains(".")?"ht":"f")+"tp://"+s`

Comment: @HermanLauenstein Pretty obvious change now that I see it, but I hadn't thought of it at all, so thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 59 bytes

```
<?=strpos($s=$argn,':')?$s:(strpos($s,'.')?ht:f)."tp://$s";
```

To run all the tests:

```
cat <<EOF | php -nF <filename>
dan-pc
https://localhost/
ftp://foo
http://foo
f.oo
derp.me
another.one/
EOF
```

(Put a newline before the `<?=` for formatting, not required for one line of input)

Or just one at a time:

```
echo '<input>' | php -nF <filename>
```

Or [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYpBCsMgEEX3HiMIJpCMe9uQXe8hidZCOjM4c/5aCaWbz@O9z4VbM/dtFa1MMlpZbaxPnF1w02YljP8wO@iqaMgTDMrBeyvDrbUj4sK7KaosXZ60x7OQqDf5emWiK/4wQ58jVYZ3MhFJS6pAmPyHWF@E0hZ8fAE)

Comment: I think you have to use a regex; your current code fails for the `a://b` example.

Comment: @Titus Oh, I didn't see that new test case. Thanks for letting me know. Do you think it'd be acceptable to just do `'p:'` instead of `':'`, since it fulfills the test cases, or would it be more "right" to use a regex?

Comment: I´d say it´d be fair to be precise, as all other submissions are so too: `%^(ht|f)tps?://%` should be ok though.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 64 bytes

```
^(?!(https?|ftp)://)(?=.*\.)
http://
^(?!(https?|ftp)://)
ftp://
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P07DXlEjo6SkoNi@Jq2kQNNKX19Tw95WTytGT5MLJA4U4MKmiCsNLPf/f5pefj4A)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>58</s> 55 bytes

```
.'://':a/.,(\0=['https'.4<'ftp']:l?)*{}{.'.'?)!)l=a@}if
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCoMwEETv@YsKslXa3R56kor9D/WQalKFmA1JbuK3p0F6GYaZefNlo8PkVxdTMdii3PuE0BBBIwlv1@HR9rDE6ALg8wU6Ohgb01X1fuwICF11qUwr38eq0whQH6Wt0yzt3U3ixPKV4UmahUMkkfkcaOaz/FuNWWblHW5KSMtxUR7ZKhJEQubR5wc)

This is my first GolfScript program, so I expect there is a lot room for golfing.

Explanation:

```
.'://':a/.,(\0=['https'.4<'ftp']:l?)*{}{.'.'?)!)l=a@}if Full program, implicit input
.                                                       Copy input
 '://':a                                                Push '://', and assign it to a
        /.                                              Split input at '://' and copy
          ,(                                            Push length of the result - 1 (<==> '://' in input)
            \0=                                         Pull up the array and get the first element
               ['https'.4<'ftp']:l                      Push [ 'https', 'http', 'ftp' ] and assign it to l
                                  ?)                    Test if first element is in that array
                                    *{}{            }if If at least one of those values is false
                                        .'.'?)          Push whether the input contains a dot
                                              !)        Logical not and increment:
                                                              '.' in input -> 1
                                                           no '.' in input -> 2
                                                l=      Get that element of l ([ 'https', 'http', 'ftp' ])
                                                  a@    Append a ('://') and input
                                                        Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 58 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```
J"://"I:Q."(|e<UGÐÌ@ãy!'"ZQ.?I}\.Q++"http"JQ.?++"ftp"J
```

[**Test suite**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%22%3A%2F%2F%22I%3AQ.%22%28%7C%06%C2%90%C2%9De%3CUG%C3%90%C3%8C%40%C3%A3%11y%21%27%22ZQ.%3FI%7D%5C.Q%2B%2B%22http%22JQ.%3F%2B%2B%22ftp%22J&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22dan-pc%22%0A%22https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F%22%0A%22ftp%3A%2F%2Ffoo%22%0A%22http%3A%2F%2Ffoo%22%0A%22f.oo%22%0A%22derp.me%22%0A%22another.one%2F%22%0A%22%2F%2F%22%0A%22a%3A%2F%2Fb%22&debug=0)

#### Code contains unprintable characters, and as such does not display properly on Stack Exchange. The link provided contains these characters and is the correct version of the program.